# CREATE DATABASE inside transaction

Tags: postgresql

According to postgresql docs;

```
CREATE DATABASE cannot be executed inside a transaction block.
```

Is there a technical reason for this?

Comment: What kind of transaction would that be?

Comment: @Lutz_Horn Are you approaching it from the POV that a transaction is applied against a database and therefore cannot include creating a database?

Answer (score 9):

When you try it, you get the error:

```
ERROR:  CREATE DATABASE cannot run inside a transaction block
```

This comes from `src/backend/access/transam/xact.c` (line 3023 on my sources, but varies by version), in `PreventTransactionChain(...)`.

The comment there explains that:

> This routine is to be called by statements that must not run inside
>    a transaction block, typically because they have non-rollback-able
>    side effects or do internal commits.

For `CREATE DATABASE` it's called from `src/backend/tcop/utility.c` in `standard_ProcessUtility` under the case for `T_CreatedbStmt`, but unfortunately there isn't any informative comment that says why specifically `CREATE DATABASE` isn't safe to run in a transaction.

Looking at the sources, I can see that for one thing it forces a checkpoint.

Overall, though, I don't see anything that really screams out "we can't do this transactionally". It's more "we haven't implemented the functionality to do this transactionally".

Answer (score 2):

It's conceptual reason: files creation has no relation to DB transaction and there is no guaranty that during the rollback they will be deleted.

Comment: Well, you might use the same argument for `CREATE TABLE` or `CREATE INDEX`, but they're transactional.

Comment: Yes they are and it's supported by WALL logging mechanism. Let's call it "exception" because not all DB vendors agree to keep them transactional. This is community developed software, so different concepts are implemented. DB/TS can be made transactional but only few people will really use it. Dynamic table creation used by many people but not all DBA's agree to allow it, try to convince them regarding dynamically created DB's...hmm... never.

Comment: Just think about isolation and atomicity - very problematic to implement.

Comment: Heh, I was just trying to argue someone out of dynamically creating DBs the other day. People will do all sorts of crazy things. (I don't disagree with you, I just think your answer is inadequate and fails to actually explain / answer the question).